# Setting up individual developer accounts in AWS Landing zone seup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

At the bottom left corner, it says Developer accounts which is in addition to the Product accounts that we have i.e Sandbox/dev/test/prod/tools

[image]

1. Is it recommended to have individual developer accounts?
2. How to set up individual developer accounts when using the Landing zone set up.  (As of now, all users login to the landing zone account and assume role in sandbox/dev/test/prod accounts.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it recommended to have individual developer accounts?

Playground/sandbox environments are a very [effective pattern for building cloud skills](https://cloudfoundation.meshcloud.io/maturity-model/tenant-management/playground-sandbox-environments.html) with your teams. Using them at scale however requires good discipline around budgets (alerts!) and decomissioning process. Unless you have the required automation in place to manage that, it's probably better to delegate that responsibility to product owners/managers (or whoever is responsible for cost and budgets of cloud environments for their teams).

> 2. How to set up individual developer accounts when using the Landing zone set up. (As of now, all users login to the landing zone account and assume role in sandbox/dev/test/prod accounts.

The assume role setup is quite tedious, AWS SSO provides a much better foundation to build on. Though you can of course also always setup individual AWS IAM users in developer accounts with a SAML Identity Provider in each account. That's quite a bit of work to automate though and is an additional hurdle to jump through for letting developers CLI/API access.

Answer (score 1):

I really dont like this phrase, but "it depends". Having dedicated accounts for each developer can be a luxury but at the same time, if resources are left unterminated, you will see a raise in the aws bill. The dev account should be specific to some projects, that the team is working on. You can also have some short live, sandbox accounts to do certain POCs.

AWS Landing Zone, comes with an Account Vending machine. It is built using the AWS Service Catalog. You should use that to create/provision new accounts.

I will recommend, to checkout the AWS Control Tower. This is the new version of AWS Landing Zone solution, released as a service